# Developing for the Windows Taskbar

Tags: windows, api, taskbar

I’m wanting to develop a custom taskbar/customize the current taskbar by using an API Windows may have, if any.

What I mean to do is create custom taskbar effects such as gradient animations, patterns, etc. I’ve searched online for docs, API or taskbar projects but can’t seem to find anything. If anyone could point me in the right direction I’d be very grateful.